# Violation operating temperature

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have a problem on my current project. Relays are failing in Cold temperature. I am using a relay which has an operating temperature +85C to -25C to PCB. And my device under test is at -40C. Can anyone help me to understand why it is happening? Note: pins of relays are mounted on the front of the PCB.

Comment: So your relay is failing when you exceed the rated temperature specification?

Comment: what is failing specifically about the relay - the coil or the contact? What is the circuit that drives the coil? How much does the coil resistance reduce at low temperatures? Why are you running relays rated at -25 at -40?

Comment: Hi Andy, that's what i am going to investigate. i just sent the damaged parts at FA Lab for Analysis.Because at first i thought it was not affected the temperature, as the body of the relays were at the back of PCB and had an approximately 10C to 20C.i think there is effect of mounted pins of relay on the top of my PCB.

Comment: Maybe OP is relying on device self-heating to ... uhm...??... warm the relays to spec??? As it stands, the relays are failing because they are out of spec, not sure why that isn't obvious to OP though. Also, why does it matter where the pins are mounted? (Front?...top? ??? ) Question needs more clearly stated info.

Answer (score 3):

Coils made of fine wire can be prone to failures from temperature extremes or cycling. If the relay coil is going open permanently, this may be the cause.

The usual reason is [differential thermal expansion](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html) and not enough allowance for motion. The relay coil bobbin may contract considerably more than the PCB in the X-Y plane, for example.

Solution would probably involve changing the relay to another type, though it's possible other solutions might work.

I would not expect conditions below the storage temperature range to destroy the relay, power applied or not. If it's a differential CTE, you might expect the relays (when soldered in anyway) to fail when in a truck or the trunk (boot) of a car on a really cold day.

Answer (score 1):

*"I am using a relay which has an operating temp. +85C to -25C to PCB. and my device under test is at -40C.  Anyone can help me to understand why it is happening?"*

Yes, lots of people can.  The +85°C to -25°C spec is called a *range*.  You are using the relay within specs if your temperature is within that range, and not if it is outside that range.  To check whether a value is within a range you perform a mathematical operation called a *comparison*.  This is where you check whether one value is less than, equal to, or greater than, some other value.  For more details, consult a 5th grade math textbook.

Let's demystify this further by working thru your case as a example.  To be within spec, your operating temperature must be *less than or equal to* (written in mathamatical equations with the symbol "≤") the high end of the range, **and** *greater than or equal to* (mathamatical symbol "≥") the bottom end of the range.  So now compare -40°C (your temperature) to +85°C (the high end of the range).  Is -40°C less than ≤ +85°C?  Yes, so you're fine there.  Is -40°C ≥ -20°C.  No, oops.  Hopefully you can now see what your mistake was.

Since you violated necessary requirements for the relay to operate correctly, you should expect that it could operate incorrectly, which is apparently what is happening.  The solution is to either stop operating this relay out of spec, or get a different relay that is specified to operate under the conditions you have.